# I using prolificinteractive-materialcalendar, but it is not work correct

Tags: android, mobile, calendar

I'm using `prolificinteractive-materialcalendar` and I made OnSelectedListener follow directions.

I want to extract selected day, and month chosen by users, but it is not working correctly.

If I choose the date July 12,

```
 calendarView.setOnDateChangedListener(new OnDateSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSelected(@NonNull MaterialCalendarView widget, @NonNull CalendarDay date, boolean selected) {

                Log.d("Test", "test1 " + date.getDate());
                Log.d("Test", "test2 " + date.getMonth());}
```

it will be printed like this:

```
test 1 Wed Jul 12 00:00:00 GMT+09:00 2017
test 2 6
```

That is, the month in incorrect (it is **6** instead of the expected **7**). I don't know reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

Formatting date is what you need.Example

```
calendarView.setOnDateChangedListener(new OnDateSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSelected(@NonNull MaterialCalendarView widget, @NonNull CalendarDay date, boolean selected) {

       DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
       String dateString = df1.format(date);



          }
```

Comment: I want to use to format "yyyy-MM-dd", and I will be split it. I need to month and day has type 'int'. because I will be use it on calculation. but one month appended again and again... I don't know why it work this way.

Comment: date.getYear() + "-" + date.getMonth()+1 + "-" + date.getDay()  here is a another way to use it. You need to plus 1 to month get correctly. It start with 0. January = 0

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was realized why he did it, by your reply. It is big help for me.